# Replace values of each array in pyspark dataframe array column by their corresponding ids

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `pyspark.sql` dataframe that looks like this:

| id | name | refs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B, C ,D |
| 2 | B | A |
| 3 | C | A, B |

I'm trying to build a function that replaces the values of each array in `ref` by the corresponding `ID` of the name that it references and if there's no matching name in the `Name` column then it would ideally filter that value out or set it to `null`. The results would ideally look something like this:

| id | name | refs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2, 3 |
| 2 | B | 1 |
| 3 | C | 1, 2 |

I tried doing this by defining a UDF that collects all names from the table and then obtains the indices of the intersection between each ref array and the set of all names. It works but is extremely slow, I'm sure there's probably better ways to do this using Spark and/or SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `explode` the arrays, do a self-join using the exploded ref and name, and collect the joined ids back to an array using `collect_list`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1 = df.select('id', 'name', F.explode('refs').alias('refs'))
df2 = df.toDF('id2', 'name2', 'refs2')

result = df1.join(df2, df1.refs == df2.name2) \
            .select('id', 'name', 'id2') \
            .groupBy('id', 'name') \
            .agg(F.collect_list('id2').alias('refs'))

result.show()
+---+----+------+
| id|name|  refs|
+---+----+------+
|  1|   A|[2, 3]|
|  2|   B|   [1]|
|  3|   C|[1, 2]|
+---+----+------+
```

Comment: I had to replace `collect_list` by `collect_set` to avoid duplicated id values. Otherwise this did perfectly. Thanks a lot